# Magento 1.9 Custom Feedback form

Tags: magento-1.9, email, forms, contact-form

I was added feedback form code in manual every layout (1column.phtml, 2col-left.phtml and etc). Now Feedback form will be showing on every page of my [site](http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/).

I need to configure email sent options. I tried normal html/php form action it will return blank. No email was received from feedback form.

### My Feedback code is,

[image]

---

Can you help me?. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you show the feed back link to every page?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, use Magento method to send email. 
Check this link : http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/